# What should I choose between the Georgia Tech MSCS and CMU MCDS programs?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, computer-science, industry, early-career

I am admitted to both the Georgia Tech MSCS (Specialization in Machine Learning), and the CMU MCDS programs. Georgia Tech costs me around 30k USD while CMU costs me 120k USD. Both are 1.5 year long. My main goal is having a good ROI. I am not interested in research. I want to do a good job in the industry. What should I choose?

Comment: Sorry, we don't take questions like this because the answers would just be partially-informed opinions, and your best course of action might be something else altogether. But here's my partially-informed opinion: while CMU is obviously the better school, Georgia Tech is still a _very_ good school for machine learning, and $90K is a LOT of money, especially in early career when you'd be probably be taking loans.